# Simple OS kernel -- screen output long string array issue

Tags: operating-system, kernel

I am following the steps in: "Writing a Simple Operating System from Scratch". I got the basic kernel up and running, but got a strange error when I try to output a very long string.

The following code output all "0"s. But when I use a shorter "msg" string, then the screen prints "x".

I wonder if anybody can help me, thanks much! (I am testing it in Bochs in windows 8).

Here is the kernel.c

```
void start () 
{
    // Create a pointer to a char , and point it to the first text cell of
    // video memory (i.e. the top - left of the screen )

    unsigned char *video_memory = ( unsigned char*) 0xb8000;
    // At the address pointed to by video_memory , store the character 'X'
    // (i.e. display 'X' in the top - left of the screen ).

    // this string: the outputs are "0"s.  
    const char msg[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzAbcdefghijkAbcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzA";

    // this string: output are "x"s.
    //const char msg[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijk";

    int i = 0;
    int offset = 0;

    while(i<85)
    {
        // Test if msg points to the right memory
        if(msg[i]==0)   
        {
            video_memory[offset] = '0';
        }           
        else
        {           
            video_memory[offset] = 'x';
        }

        video_memory[offset+1] = 0x02; // Green color

        i = i + 1;
        offset = offset + 2;

        //set_cursor(offset);   
    }
}
```

Comment: I checked the binary code last night, the "msg" string doesn't look right when the string is too long. It could be compiler or linker issue. 

I also tried fixed size char array: 

// this one output "0"s. 
char msg[100] ="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzAbcdefghijkAbcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzA

or 

// this one output "x"s.
char msg[100] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijk"

so, same error.

Comment: a) How are you compiling and linking that code? b) How is `start` being called? If you don't want to pass any parameters then better use `void start(void)`.

Comment: Thanks! 

(a) I compiled it in windows:

(i) $gcc -ffreestanding -c kernel.c -o kernel.o
(ii) ld -T NUL -o kernel.tmp -Ttext 0x1000 kernel_entry.o kernel.o
(iii) objcopy -O binary -j .text  kernel.tmp kernel.bin
(iv) copy /b boot_sect.bin+kernel.bin os-image

(b)
start() is called in kernel_entry.asm: 
[ bits 32] ; We 're in protected mode by now , so use 32- bit instructions.
[ extern _start ] ; Declare external start, so the linker can substitute the final address
call _start ; invoke main () in our C kernel

Comment: Please add that to the question (comments may vanish, and it's hard to read in a comment). Are you using a linker script? If so, please post its contents. Also produce a map of the linking, using option `-Map mapfile`, and add its contents. I'm suspecting that the `.rodata` section is put at a wrong memory address.